# Magento cron - question about timings

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, cron

If my main crontab runs the magento cron.php every 30 mins and i have a cron job set in a modules config.xml to run every 15 mins.  Will that mean the modules cron gets run:

1. Once every 30 mins
2. Twice every 30 mins

Comment: I think that you will find that some ISP's will halt cron that run more frequently than 30 minutes. Siteground in particular d.

Comment: The nice thing about Magento cron is that you can call it through a URL. If this is the case just set up a cron on another server like so `*/5 * * * * wget http://domain.com/cron.php 2> /dev/null` or setup it up from any Windows PC

Comment: Be careful with the cron.php - it runs asynchronously; there may be some cron processes from 3rd party vendors that depend on running to completion before issuing another call. Think cart abandonment reminders....

Comment: And his service provider may have him restricted to cron every 30 minutes. Ours is rather high end and they demand a minimum of 15 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a swath of configuration options for cron in the Magento admin under System Configuration -> System -> Cron. The one titled "Missed if Not Run Within" is, by default, set to 15 minutes and will affect what you're trying to determine. With this set at it's default of 15 minutes…

…the job scheduled for every 15 with crontab executing every 30 would (theoretically) be run only once per 30 minutes with the job scheduled for the 15 minute mark being marked as missed. However, this cannot be relied on, as the timing of the cron cycle being off by a few seconds could land it occasionally within the 15 minute period and run it twice in one cycle. So don't *rely* on it only running once every 30 minutes.

My suggestion would be to set the crontab to run every 5 minutes, then control the jobs actual scheduling using the [AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) module... which I've heard so much about, but haven't yet used it much myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say once.

But dont understand why you run cron.php only every 30 min instead of every min.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out the [Aoe Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) extension. It gives you a great overview of the running crons.

Magento should run all cronjobs that are scheduled to run AFTER the last run so it should execute the cron twice every 30 minutes. If you check out the class `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer` the jobs are retrieved as an collection in the method `getPendingSchedules`.
You can see that it only filters on status `pending` and since two jobs were added during the 30 minutes with that status it will execute them .

I'd advice you to run the cron every 5 minuten just to ensure Magento and the 3th party extensions using cronjobs runs properly

Comment: but how can magento delay them or does it run both directly after each other every 30 mins and not once every 15 mins?

Comment: the cronjobs from the the extensions are stored in the table `cron_schedule`. Only when you call `cron.php` or `cron.sh` by your Linux cronjob that you run every 30 minutes that table is processed and the jobs are executed.
So every 30 minutes it'll iterate trough all jobs in the table and run those jobs.

Comment: It runs both when the 30 minute trigger event occurs. So if you're calling cron.sh/cron.php every 30min and you have a job that schedules every 15, it will schedule two jobs that supposedly run 15 minutes apart which will both run on the next 30 minute trigger. It's annoying, just got through with an abandoned cart remailer scheduled for 5 min intervals on a 15 minute trigger. It was blasting out three emails for each abandoned cart every 15 minutes. Changed the abandoned cart remail to 15 minute intervals and the customer now gets a single email per abandoned cart. The AOE Sched helped see it